# Vue setFieldValue sorting based on keys on its own

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've this function I use to upload from csv and save the details in an array and save it

```
getArray(row) {
  let getDetail = []
  if (row['comment'].trim().length > 0) {
    this.setFieldValue(getDetail, 'Comments', row['comment'])
  }
  if (row['start'].trim().length > 0) {
    this.setFieldValue(getDetail, 'Start Date', this.dateFormat(row['start']))
  }
  if (row['end'].trim().length > 0) {
    this.setFieldValue(getDetail, 'End Date', this.dateFormat(row['end']))
  }
  return getDetail
},
```

The issue is getDetail is automatically sorted based on keys, so on UI on the table I am displaying it using `v-for`

I've order as -> `Comment, End date, Start date` 
where as the required is -> `Comment, Start date, End date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to avoid using the name as key.

Comment: I've not used the same name as key, 
Keys are
`Comment` `Start Date` `End Date`

Comment: Yes, don't use that keys or you will loose the sorting. You have to use an array where the keys are incrementing integers.

Comment: Hey thanks that worked, but can you please point me to the doc for it? would like to know more about it, I am unable to find more info on it

Comment: Sorry I think there is no reference in doc for it. It is a general rule that arrays are always sorted by keys, and if that keys are string the it will sort by that string. In general, don't use string keys for array.